# Application Switcher on both monitors in dual-head setup?

Tags: unity, compiz, application-switcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show the Alt-Tab popup on All Monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130127/how-to-show-the-alt-tab-popup-on-all-monitors)

I have a dual-head setup, and everything is working fine, but I would like the application switcher window to show up in both monitors at the same time when I switch applications. Is that possible to set up somehow? I didn't find anything in CCSM.

I'm using the static application switcher right now, but I would use a different switcher if it has that feature.

Comment: See also: [this question about the default unity switcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130127/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-show-the-alt-tab-popup-on-all-monitors).

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open CCSM. Go to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin", Click on the "Switcher" tab and disable "Bias alt-tab to prefer windows on the current viewport" option.

This should work to display on both monitors.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question.