# How to show the Alt-Tab popup on All Monitors?

Tags: unity

By default, it seems that the Alt-Tab popup for switching between applications shows on whichever monitor contains the active window. Is there anyway to duplicate the alt-tab popup on both monitors all at once?

If not, is there a way to force it to always appear on one distinct monitor so it doesn't always seem random?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Switcher on both monitors in dual-head setup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81233/application-switcher-on-both-monitors-in-dual-head-setup)

Comment: @fluteflute it is related, however that question is about the compiz static application switcher, and my question is about the built-in Unity switcher. I think they use separate configurations.

Comment: that's fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 13.10 (and possibly earlier) this has been fixed. The Alt + Tab program switcher now displays on the monitor **where the mouse cursor is located**, regardless of where the active window is. Thus, it is more intuitive.

Comment: No, sorry, this is not a "fix" because the original ask was to display the UI on both monitors, nothing to do with the one currently holding the mouse.  And the idea of basing this off where the mouse is also doesn't make much sense since the entire idea of alt-tab is using the keyboard INSTEAD of the mouse.

Comment: Except in Ubuntu 20.04 it doesn't :-(

Comment: That's unfortunate that it changed with Ubuntu 20.04. I imagine it also may have changed with the switch from Unity to Gnome, somewhere around the 18.04 release. 
@dreadwail actually the original ask had a follow up "If not, is there a way to force it to always appear on one distinct monitor so it doesn't always seem random?" which is what I was referring to with the switcher at least having some consistency by following the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible in Unity without modifying the source code to implement this feature, sorry.

Comment: This is a huge oversight... And makes app switcher almost unusable at times.