# Alt+Tab task switcher on all monitors

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-classic, window-management

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic and using dual monitors. In this set up I see the task switcher (activated with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) is shown only in the monitor with the mouse pointer. Does anybody know how to make it appear on all monitors?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do this. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130127/how-to-show-the-alt-tab-popup-on-all-monitors

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your screen are not "single" screen and are independent from each other. You can see this in GDM setting, each screen as their own view port.

You only can use one active screen at a time. If <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Tab</kbd> are working at the same time on all monitors, you still only have one pointer to make the screen active.

So it defies the reason of having task switcher.