# Place Compiz Static Application Switcher always on a certain monitor

Tags: compiz, multiple-monitors, application-switcher, window-placement

variants of this question have been asked, namely, how to place the switcher on both monitors [when using compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81233/application-switcher-on-both-monitors-in-dual-head-setup) and [when using Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130127/how-to-show-the-alt-tab-popup-on-all-monitors), neither are possible from what I see.

Having it on both monitors would be great but I would also be happy to have it on a fixed monitor, so your eyes don't need to jump, or at least on the monitor that has the mouse.

(for the mouse part, I found [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/739035), but with little activity and older compiz. I'm using 12.04, compiz 0.9.7.12-0ubuntu3)

I want to propose yet another workaround, but for which I need help, namely, to use the "Place" compiz plugin that seems to be able to force placement on the monitor with the mouse. But to do it **I need the Class of the Static Switcher window, how can I find it?**

Comment: Hi haelix, what is exactly the question? Perhaps you would need to divide this into more than one post.

Comment: An answer would be valid if it solves the problem in any way (via any workaround). I think people who struggle with this would appreciate the detailed post.

Comment: But, to put it simply, **the question** can be what's written in **bold**.

Comment: What is in bold is not a question.

Comment: What you're saying is that it doesn't have a question mark, but still, the sentence obviously implies a question, such as: **what is the Class of the Static Switcher window?** or equivalently, **how can I find the Class of the Static Switcher window**? (it it's a window at all)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the "alt+tab" (I don't know how it's called), then it doesn't have a Class.

It has however a Name: `Switcher`.

You can find everything by using xprop:

```
sleep 2 && xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d\  -f 5)
```

Type this in a terminal, then press alt+tab without letting the alt key up, and you will get the results for the Switcher window.

EDIT: The following is the full output of `xprop` for the switcher window. Apparently it doesn't work on every situation.

```
_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 7, 733, 48, 48
XKLAVIER_STATE(INTEGER) = 0, 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 0, 0
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Switcher"
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER, _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED
```

Comment: Hi, nice try, but that only gets the details for the terminal window in my case (even with Alt pressed). Could be we're using different switchers, like I said, I'm using the "static application switcher" (12.04 by default doesn't alt+tab, so I go to CCSM > Window Management > enable Static Application Switcher)

Comment: I tried enabling the Static Application Switcher in CCSM but I could still get the results. By the way I have alt+tab without enabling this option. I don't remember the default behaviour of Ubuntu Precise nor how I changed it though :)

Comment: You might be using Unity, I don't. I think it was incorrect to say 'the default is no Alt+Tab'. Actually, after switching to gnome fallback, then you don't get Alt+Tab

Comment: Oh.. I see. You should mention that you don't use unity in the question then :)