# how to place application switcher only on secondary monitor?

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, compiz, xfce, application-switcher

I have two monitors on Xubuntu 19.10 with Xfce 4.14.
When I use `Alt + Tab` to switch from one app to another the switcher window appears on the both monitors.
As workaround I installed `compiz` and the switchers from this package appear only on one monitor which is actually active.

What I really want that the switcher window will appear always only on my secondary monitor, no matter on which monitor the active application located.
How can I achieve this?

*p.s. I try solutions from [Place Compiz Static Application Switcher always on a certain monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382400/place-compiz-static-application-switcher-always-on-a-certain-monitor) with out luck.*